# Finding the object property with the highest value where the property is a decimal

Tags: javascript, math-functions

I'm currently using:

```
last = Math.max.apply(Math, response.data.map((o: any) => {
   return o.name; 
}))
```

to find the object with the highest 'name' value within response.data array. Despite 16.12 being the largest value, it returns 16.9 as I think it's just looking at the 1 and skipping it. How can I make it take into account the full decimal?

Edited: 
The data coming through is:

[image]

Comment: please add the data as well. why is `16.12` greater than `16.9`?

Comment: @NinaScholz edited to add data

Comment: i see no problem with the code. can you explain a bit more what data is giving the false result?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding @NatalieM 16.9 is greater than 16.12, which is why you're getting that answer.

Comment: Yeah given what I want, a math function might not be the most appropriate...First of all the data is referring to release versions and they come in as strings. I had converted to floats as I thought it working with them as string would be trickier. So release 16.9 is older than 16.12 but once converted into floats it isn't. I've found a work around since the first item in the data returned is the latest (16.12) which removes the need for converting. Thanks guys!

Comment: @NatalieM you should not be relying on the first is the max value

Comment: Yeah I mean it's not my preferred method but when converting "16.12.3"  for example I can't get the full thing

Comment: And I take it unless they are non strings I can't compare for the highest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of [SemVer](https://semver.org/) the individual components, **major**, **minor** and **patch** are integers however the composite value, **major.minor.patch** is not a valid number itself. This is why they are stored as strings, the period is merely a delimiter and not a decimal point.

To correctly compare versions you need to break the strings into their component parts and compare each pair of numbers individually. The following example does this by sorting in descending order then taking the first value.

> **Note:** As it is unclear from the question what exactly the requirements are, abbreviated versions ***e.g.*** `1.1`, will be treated as `1.1.0` here for the sake of simplicity - where typically it is more idiomatic to say that `1.1` represents the highest version of `1.1.x` available for a given set.

```js
const cmpVersionDesc = (a, b) => {
    const as = a.split('.').map(Number)
    const bs = b.split('.').map(Number)

    return (bs[0]||0) - (as[0]||0)
        || (bs[1]||0) - (as[1]||0)
        || (bs[2]||0) - (as[2]||0)
}

const latestVersion = versions => 
    [...versions].sort(cmpVersionDesc)[0]
    
 const versions = [
    '16.9',
    '16.12',
    '16.12.1',
    '16.1'
]

console.log('latest', latestVersion(versions)) // '16.12.1'
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const array = [{
    name: 16.3
  },
  {
    name: 16
  },
  {
    name: 17
  },
  {
    name: 17.3
  },
  {
    name: 19
  }
]


console.log(Math.max(...array.map(({name}) => name % 1 !== 0 && name)))
```

Comment: That still gives me 16.9, what would happen if you changed your other 17 value to 17.11?

Comment: that's impossible.. change the values inside the answer and you should be getting the highest decimal again.

Comment: can you provide the full json data in your question, or at least a part of it?